# Firebug Shows 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: http, tinymce, http-status-code-301

Im using yii framework with tiny mce. When I run my website in localhost it works just fine. But when I upload to the server the editor doesnt show up. when I check in Firebug, it show :

http://www.ptbm.co.id/veevou/assets/dde67fde/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php?s=true&diskcache=true&core=t.......

then the status is 301 moved permanently

This is the request code :

```
// Send request
    x = w.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : get('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') || get('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    x.overrideMimeType && x.overrideMimeType('text/javascript');
    x.open('GET', t.baseURL + '/' + s.page_name + '?' + q, !!cb);
    //x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    x.send('');
```

The url correctly pointing to existing file.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: A status of 301 moved permanently is a redirect. What does the Location header say?

Comment: It says nothing. It suppose to point a php file but it keeps showing error 301 moved permanently in firebug and error 404 Not Found

Comment: I am having the same issue. can you please give some update, if you have solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your server redirects to a URL without the `www` prefix:

```
$ curl -I 'http://www.ptbm.co.id/veevou/assets/dde67fde/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php?s=true&diskcache=true&core=t'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2011 09:14:48 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
X-Pingback: http://ptbm.co.id/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Last-Modified: Fri, 18 Nov 2011 09:14:49 GMT
Location: http://ptbm.co.id/veevou/assets/dde67fde/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php?s=true&diskcache=true&core=t
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

You could remove that `RewriteRule`, or make sure that `t.baseUrl` does not have any `www` prefix.

Without more code it is difficult to give any more exact pointers than that.

Comment: I tried to hard code it : x.open('GET', 'http://www.ptbm.co.id/veevou/assets/dde67fde/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php'); but it doesnt work also

Comment: No, because the target URL returns `404 Not found`. Perhaps you have a `VirtualHost` that requires the `www` prefix to find the proper `DocumentRoot`? There's probably an error somewhere in your server config, but I won't be able to guess what it is unless you post more info.

Comment: Hm, i see. Thanks for the clue =) I'll check the server config then